# c++ , can we cast a child class object into parent class type or vise versa.?

Tags: c++

I tried this code but getting this compilation error

```
class A{
};
class B : public A{
};
int main()
{
A a = new B();  // ERROR: "No suitable constructor exists to convert from "B*" to "A".

B b = new A();  // ERROR: "No suitable constructor exists to convert from "A*" to "B".
}
```

I am new to C++ and trying to learn . Can someone help me to understand this.

Comment: `A* a = new B();` will compile as this yields a pointer. The vice versa way isn't possible.

Comment: you can use an [online compiler](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/) to test what compiles

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: thanks a lot. It understand what i was missing.
A* a = new B(); worked.

Answer (score 1):

Only way it makes a sense is to have a parent type containing a derived class. This way you can call all virtual methods of the derived class and non-virtual of parent class. Also when stored like this, you can dynamic_cast it to from derived to parent class (e.g `A* a = dynamic_cast<A*>(new B());`)
An other example would be:

```
std::vector<A> vec;
vec.push_back(B());
A* ptr = new B();
std::unique_ptr<A> unique = std::make_unique<B>();
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you use new only when you are dealing with pointer objects.
like

```
 A * a = new A();
```

other wise use 
     A a;

Secondly, you have to explictly do the downcasting i.e:

```
 B * b = (B*) (new A());
```

Comment: `A a();` is a function declaration. Maybe you meant `A a;`

Comment: @Misgevolution you probably meant downcasting in the latter code snippet

Comment: @FdeF yes, thanks for your suggestion.